# Where is $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ decreasing?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given a function

$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$

How do I find the interval in which it is decreasing?

My try: I differentiated the function using the division rule and finally got $f'(x)=x^{2}-1$. How do I reach to any conclusion from there?

Comment: If the function is differentiable then it is increasing exactly when the derivative is positive.

Comment: Once you finally get $f'(x)$ straightened out, you need to solve the inequality $f'(x) \le 0$: a (differentiable) function is non-increasing wherever its derivative is at most $0$.

Comment: Your derivative is wrong.

Comment: The question has a subtle issue of wording. It should ask for the **intervals**  (plural) on which the function is decreasing. Or maybe interval(s).

Comment: Your derivative is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I got the answer. The function $f'(x)$ comes out to be $\frac{x^{2}-1}{x^{2}}$. For a function to be nonincreasing, this value must be less than (or equal to) zero. From this we conclude that x should be $[-1,1]$. But since $x$ can not be equal to zero, the final answer comes out to be $[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$.

Comment: You asked for an interval, right?

Comment: Yes and that's what I'm getting

Comment: The set $[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$ is not an interval.

Comment: Hence, whatever the function of interest, "the final answer" to the question "How do I find the interval in which it is decreasing?" cannot be: $[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{d(1/x)}{dx}=1+\frac{d(1/x)}{dx}$$
$$f(x)=1,~f'(x)=0,~g(x)=x,~g'(x)=1$$
$$\frac{d(1/x)}{dx}=\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)'=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{0\cdot x-1\cdot1}{(x)^2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

$$\frac{df}{dx}=1-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$1-\frac{1}{x^2}\leq 0\Rightarrow x^2-1\leq0\Rightarrow x^2\leq1\Rightarrow-1\leq x\leq1$$
Provided of course that $x\neq0$

Answer (score -1):

$f(x) = x + 1/x = x + x^{-1}$

$f'(x) = 1 + (-1)x{-2} = 1 - x^{-2} = 1 - 1/x^2$.

$f(x)$ is increasing when $f'(x) > 0$.  And non-increasing when $f'(x) \le 0$.

If $1 - 1/x^2 \le 0$ then $1 \le 1/x^2$ $x^2 \le 1$ so $-1 < x < 1$.  But $x$ can not equal $0$.  But then again $x$ is not increasing or decreasing or constant at $x = 1$.

So we need to know what the definition of "non-increasing" is.

If "non-increasing" means "not increasing" then  $f(x)$ is non-increasing on $[-1,1]$.

If "non-increasing" means "constant or decreasing" then $f(x)$ is non-increasing on $[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$.

Comment: "If "non-increasing" means "not increasing" then  $f(x)$ is non-increasing on $[-1,1]$." No, a function cannot be nonincreasing on an interval if it is not defined at every point in the interval.

Comment: The function does not exist at 0.  Is the function increasing at 0?  No, it is not.  Is the function increasing on any point in [-1,1]?  No, it is not. If non-increasing means "not increasing" then the is the function not increasing at any point in [-1,1]? No, it is not increasing on any point.  So it is "non-increasing" at every point.  But *does* "non-increasing" mean "not increasing"?  No I don't think it should.

Comment: Why are you commenting on a post over two years old.  Before the post was edited three days after I wrote this, the original post wanted to know where the function was "not increasing".  Well it isn't *anything* where it isn't defined.  My point was "non-increasing" is *not* the same as "non-increasing" (because anything is not X where it doesn't exist but to be non-X it must exist).  The OP was treating them as equivalent.