# When is this function increasing?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The function is given by $f(x)=\sin^{4}x+\cos^{4}x$.

My try -- Okay so I differentiated this function and if I solved correctly which I hope I did I got $ \sin2x(\cos2x)>0 $.But im not getting the correct answer.

Ok here is how I differentiated it -- 
$4\sin^{3}x\cdot \cos x-4\sin x\cdot \cos^{3}x =$ 
$4\sin  x\cdot\cos x(\sin^{2}x-\cos^{2}x)=$ 
$2\sin 2x(-\cos2x)$

Now this should be positive for function to be increasing so 
$2\sin 2x(-\cos 2x)>0$ 
$\sin 2x(\cos 2x)>0$(since cos is an even function and -ve sign can be ignored).

Okay can someone tell how to proceed from here. What will be the values of $x$ in radians such that this function is increasing?

Comment: It seems you like derivatives :-) you had a similar question very recently :-) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850601/where-is-fx-x-frac1x-non-increasing/1850611#1850611

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :** 
$$2\sin2x\cos2x=\sin4x$$

Comment: Thanks for the conclusion but according to that I'll get $sin4x>0$.And the answer that I'm supposed to get is $x$ should be from $45°$ to $67.5°$.But see if those are the values of $x$ then my equation is certainly wrong.

Comment: you have to consider $2\sin2x(-\cos2x)>0\iff 2\sin2x\cos2x=\sin4x<0 \iff x \in [\pi/4+k\pi/2,\pi/2+k\pi/2]$. You find thus 45°, the 67.5° must depends of the bounds of $x$ given by your exercise.
And your derivative is correct !

Comment: Jennifer did you take the negative sign out of $cos$?If you did then why? Can't the negative sign just be ignored as $cos$ is an even function?

Comment: The fact that$\cos$ is usfull when the minus sign is *inside* the $\cos$ :  it says that $\cos -x=\cos x$. it does NOT say that $-\cos x = \cos x$ this second statement is actually equivalent to $\cos x = 0$

Comment: Wow great work Jennifer. Thanks a lot! Do you have kik or any other website we can talk to each other?

Comment: Glad to help, and no sorry I don't have.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$f(x)=\sin^4x+\cos^4x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-\dfrac{\sin^22x}2=1-\dfrac{1-\cos4x}4=?$$

Now check when $f'(x)>0$

Answer (score 0):

Since $-sin(4x)>0$ for function to be increasing, so $sin(4x)<0$ .

We know that $sin$ is negative in third and fourth quadrant. So 
$$4x\in (2n\pi+\pi,2n\pi+2\pi)$$ where $n\in I$

SO finally $$x\in (\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{4},\frac{(2n+2)\pi}{4})$$
which is the final answer

Hope this will be helpful !

Comment: Okay great! That explains it correctly. But could you tell how'd you get $-sin4x$. Did you take out the negative sign of $cos2x$?If yes then why? Can't it be ignored as $cos$ is an increasing fucntion?

Comment: $f'(x)=2sin(2x)\times (-cos(2x))=-2sin(2x)cos(2x)=-sin(4x)$. Use the Identity $sin(2x)=2sin(x)cos(x)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Using the complex definition with $z=e^{ix}$, the expression is proportional to

$$(z-z^{-1})^4+(z+z^{-1})^4=2z^4+12+2z^{-4},$$ which is linearly related to $\cos 4x$.

Answer (score 0):

$ \cos x $ is even means $\cos x = \cos (-x) $ not $\cos x = - \cos x $

Comment: This has already been answered.